# Enabling ssl in mongodb replicaset without certificates

Tags: mongodb, ssl

I am trying to set up a mongodb 2.6.8 replicaset using ssl. I compiled mongo manually with ssl support and enabled ssl in my configuration as follows:

```
sslMode=requireSSL
sslPEMKeyFile=/etc/ssl/mongodb.pem
sslCAFile=/etc/ssl/client.pem
sslWeakCertificateValidation=true
replSet=rs0
```

I created the mongodb.pem and client.pem files bu running openssl as follows on each server:

```
# openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out mongodb-cert.crt -keyout mongodb-cert.key -subj '/C=US/ST=MA/L=Waltham/CN=<fully qualified domain name>'
# cat mongodb-cert.key mongodb-cert.crt > mongodb.pem
# openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out client-cert.crt -keyout client-cert.key -subj '/C=US/ST=MA/L=Waltham/CN=<fully qualified domain name>'
# cat client-cert.key client-cert.crt > client.pem
```

On each server I can confirm that the certificates and ssl is working because on each of my servers I can do the following:

```
mongo --ssl --sslPEMKeyFile=/etc/ssl/client.pem --sslCAFile=/etc/ssl/mongodb.pem <fully qualified domain name>
```

drops me into the mongo shell.

On the primary node, I can do rs.initiate() and rs.status() and it looks fine:

```
> rs.initiate()
{
    "info2" : "no configuration explicitly specified -- making one",
    "me" : "<fqdn node 1>:27017",
    "info" : "Config now saved locally.  Should come online in about a minute.",
    "ok" : 1
}
> rs.status()
{
    "set" : "rs0",
    "date" : ISODate("2015-04-02T20:25:27Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "<fqdn node 1>:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 23,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1428006318, 1),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-04-02T20:25:18Z"),
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1428006318, 2),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2015-04-02T20:25:18Z"),
            "self" : true
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

However, when I attempt to add the second member, I get the dreaded 13144 error:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> rs.add("<fqdn node 2>:27017")
{
    "errmsg" : "exception: need most members up to reconfigure, not ok : <fqdn node 2>:27017",
    "code" : 13144,
    "ok" : 0
}
```

I should also note that connecting between the two hosts works fine, i.e., while on node 1:

```
mongo --ssl --host <fqdn node 2>
```

or while on node 2:

```
mongo --ssl --host <fqdn node 1>
```

both work.

How do I pass in the ssl option and/or the certificates to the rs.add() command?

I don't actually care about passing the certificates (which is why I specified sslWeakCertificateValidation=true); I'm more concerned about making sure the communication between the nodes is in ssl.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to be certain what was wrong, but I've got a few observations:

1. You may have got that error if the other mongod process was started *without* the `replSet=rs0` item in its configuration
2. You may have got that error because the servers cannot communicate on port 27017, e.g. if a firewall is blocking them. It's worth verifying the connectivity by, on each server, connecting the mongo client to the other server.
3. There is a problem with your mongod.pem file. You have created it by concatenating the server's private key and certificate; but it should **not** contain the key. It should be just an ascending chain of certificates, starting with the server and ending with the root. If the server is self-certified, then there is no need to concatenate anything else.